# Is currency filter works with numbers only using $scope.$eval()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to create a custom directive with options passed as attributes..
I've noticed that currency filter works with numbers only and it don't work if it is used with some string property only. And if i try to use this filter with property having string it don't generate any result.. is it so?
and how can i use currency filter with string value if i wants to?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('defaultCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.products = [
    {
      name: "Apples",
      category: "Fruits",
      price: 1.20,
      expiry: 10
    }, {
      name: "Bananas",
      category: "Fruits",
      price: 2.42,
      expiry: 7
    }, {
      name: "Pears",
      category: "Fruits",
      price: 2.02,
      expiry: 6
    } 
  ];
}]);

app.directive('unorderedList', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var data = scope[attrs["unorderedList"]];
    if(angular.isArray(data)) {
      var listElem = angular.element('<ul>');
      var propertyExpression = attrs["listProperty"];

      element.append(listElem);

      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        listElem.append(angular.element('<li>').text(scope.$eval(propertyExpression, data[i])));
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div id="wrapper" ng-controller="defaultCtrl">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3>Products</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div unordered-list="products" list-property="price | currency"></div>
        <div unordered-list="products" list-property="name | currency"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What would you expect currency to return for Apples, Bananas or Pears? I think it's working properly. None of the values for name can be converted to currency.

Comment: its just a test case, yes it doesn't make sense with these values.. but i've asked a question in general.. values may change

Comment: Yeah, I understand it's just a test case, but it's a test case that doesn't duplicate the problem you're asking about. At any rate, I just copied a the items you supplied a bunch of times, and didn't see performance issues. But...

Comment: 1.I would upgrade from Angular 1.01 to a more recent release.

Answer (score 0):

The source code of that filter (`currency`) stand as

```
currencyFilter.$inject = ['$locale'];
function currencyFilter($locale)
{
    var formats = $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS;
    return function(amount, currencySymbol, fractionSize)
    {
        if (isUndefined(currencySymbol))
        {
            currencySymbol = formats.CURRENCY_SYM;
        }

        if (isUndefined(fractionSize))
        {
            fractionSize = formats.PATTERNS[1].maxFrac;
        }

        // if null or undefined pass it through
        return (amount == null)
            ? amount
            : formatNumber(amount, formats.PATTERNS[1], formats.GROUP_SEP, formats.DECIMAL_SEP, fractionSize).replace(/\u00A4/g, currencySymbol);
    };
}
```

Now the code for `formatNumber` starts as follow

```
function formatNumber(number, pattern, groupSep, decimalSep, fractionSize) {

  if (!(isString(number) || isNumber(number)) || isNaN(number)) return '';
```

and [angular.isNumber](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isNumber) states that

> Determines if a reference is a Number.
>
> This includes the "special" numbers NaN, +Infinity and -Infinity

Thus, `formatNumber(...)` with your apples and bananas simply return `''` (empty string)

Answer (score 0):

Since list-property is not defined in the scope with the @ it won't get evaluated.

So as you put it there : YES you need scope.$eval.

However you can change it to :

```
list-property="{{price | currency}}"
```

And remove the scope.$eval in your directive. This should work.